# How to create a class where the type is "equal" to int?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

I am trying to create a dataclass that can generate a clickhouse (sql-ish) schema from type definitions.

clickhouse for example supports:

- Int8
- Int16
- Uint8
- Uint16

In python, these types don't exist (afaik). It's just `int`. I am hoping I can still create a type structure that let's me express it and auto generate my desired schema and maybe run validation on the types. I also hope to have my type hinter (I use PyCharm, not sure about mypy) not complain when I pass a value of type int

This is my idea so far:

```py
@dataclass
class ClickhouseType:
    @classmethod
    def schema_type(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value):
        # just included as an example, not important as part of this discussion :) 
        pass


@dataclass
class Int8(int, ClickhouseType):
    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value):
        # just included as an example, not important as part of this discussion :)
        assert -128 <= value <= 127

@dataclass
class MySchema:
    some_number: Int8


x = MySchema(some_number=4)  # type hint complaints that I pass an int when an Int8 is required
```

Is there a way to make python/my type hinter understand that I want `Int8` to be interchangeable with `int`?

Comment: The problem with that is `Int8` is an `int`, but an `int` isn't a `Int8`. Does `MySchema` need to take specifically an `Int8`? If it does, you'll run into the problem that not every `int` can be an `Int8`, and afaik, that can't be statically checked.

Comment: Also, you could try using `typing's` [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#newtype) to eliminate some boilerplate for `Int8` and such, but that doesn't help you for your current problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll look into NewType. I am ok with not every int is an Int8 as I am less worried about that than people (me) passing a string instead. I tried using a metaclass where I overwrite `__instancecheck__`, but the type hinter does not pick that. Could be a type hinter issue though :)

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Nah, `SupportsIndex` is more appropriate. `SupportsInt` includes stuff like `float`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica You're right. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your types using direct inheritance:

```
class int8 (int):
    def __new__ (cls, value):
        assert -128<=value<=127
        return int(value) # Simplified
        # Or if you need more things:
        self = int.__new__(cls, value)
        self.something = "something else"
        return self
```

Edit prompted by shadowranger's comment:

```
Everything here will be type(int(...))==type(int8(...))==True, except the classes
__name__ attribute after instancing. And int8().__class__ of course.
Remember that the __new__() constructor is called before anything else in the class is "considered objectified". Therefore before the __init__() as well. __init__() is called after the object's construction, while __new__() is called practically before it.
__new() receives the class as a first argument, while __init__() receives already constructed object.
So, if multiple inheritance is used, some of initialization should go to __new__(), mostly those modifying the data type, and some of it should be done in __init__().

Note that type(int)!=type(int8)==True here, so this is not really an exact answer to your question, but it should be a good pointer combined with what you already know.
```

Comment: Note: The first implementation (`return int(value)`) won't be an `int8`, it'll just be an `int`; returning `int(value)` really does just return a plain `int`, which is legal, if odd. It does make the class pretty pointless though; a plain function could do the same validation. I'd recommend using the second approach, and adding `__slots__ = ()` (or whatever slots you need) to the definition so it doesn't occupy significantly more memory than a normal `int`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger : You are right, of course, but the point is that if people use int8() the value will be checked by assert statement and the hinter will recognize the type being int. Yes, in this case the class is pointless because the same can be achieved using a function. But I wanted to show some of how this works without writing a lot of explanations. A kind of challenge. The second way is really a way to go. The memory "problem" cannot be avoided as the OP's implementation will include multiple inheritance it seems, not only int. This should not impact the type though.

Comment: I didn't have problems with multiple inheritance with unicode (Py 2) nor with str (Py 3). As long as the Python data type is inherited and its attributes are not drastically modified i.e. completely removed everything works fine.